# How to insert Dynamic SQL in list and labels?

Tags: datasource, dynamic-sql, substitution, bind-variables, listlabel

How to write a Dynamic SQL query with bind/substitute variables in List and Labels report server?

When creating the Datasource I have the option to enter the query manually, but as soon I enter the bind an error message is displayed.

I want to be able to enter a dynamic query in the datasource and set the value of that bind/substitution variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that's actively being worked on. [This blog post](https://blog.combit.net/en/blog/development/04-2018/introducing-parametrized-data-sources/) covers the basics for parametrized data sources within List & Label itself. Thorough support within the Report Server, including support for stored procedure parameters, is on the roadmap and will be released this fall.